# How to see models.ManyToManyField('self') in admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a field in one of my Model:

```
class Article( models.Model ):
     title = models.CharField("Title", max_length=255)
     related_articles = models.ManyToManyField('self')
```

But only super-admins can see this "related_articles" currently, there is no permission to be set for non-superadmin. This is my admin file:

```
class Article_Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_per_page       = 20
    search_fields       = ['id', 'title'']
    list_display        = ('title',)
    fieldsets           = [
        ( "Article Data", {
            '
            'fields': ['title',]
        }),
        ( "Related Articles", {
            'fields': ['related_articles']
        }),
    ]
 admin.site.register(Article, Article_Admin)
```

How to set permission for non-superadmin to see models.ManyToManyField('self') in admin page?

Comment: wierd. you don't customize any admin authentication?

Comment: by default non-superadmin cannot see models.ManyToManyField('self'), which is why i was confused and i go here to stackoverflow. I am stuck myself.

Comment: did you try making `Group`? When you make group, you can give permissions - and give permission for the model

Comment: i already set the group or the user to be able to see article. It simply does not show "related_articles". It does show it for super_admins

Comment: it does not show the "models.ManyToManyField('self')"

Comment: still not working.